# What is the expected time (instead of number of steps) to absorption in Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I was reading the following 'Absorbing Markov chain' wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain), it shows that we can get the expected number of steps (or transition) by calculating the fundamental matrix.

$P=\begin{pmatrix}
Q & R \\
0 & I_r \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$N=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}Q^k=(I_t-Q)^{-1}$

$\boldsymbol{t}=N\boldsymbol{1}$

What i wonder is that if we assume the duration of each transition is an exponentially
distributed random variable with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda_{i,j}} (i\neq j)$, where $\lambda_{i,j}$ is the rate of transition from state $i$ to state $j$, then is there any existing calculation or formula for the expected time (instead of number of steps) to absorption in the matrix form?